# How to debug why an UPDATE function isn't working in PHP?

Tags: php, html, post, content-management-system

I am working on a customized CMS to try to learn some stuff on PHP. I am basing my experience in some tutorials I see/read.

So, I have this table called `page_hem` where all the data is saved. Then I have it echoing on text fields all over the page that is for the time being my index.php. All works fine, especially if I insert the data from the phpMyAdmin.

But now I am creating the edit form and things are not working any more. I can still echo everything into text boxes so I can change the text but when I press the button "save" my variables don't update on the database despite I get the success message. I don't know if the issue is on the edit page or on the parse code; I don't get any errors, even when I am Firebugging.

**Here is the edit page:**

```
<?php
require_once "../scripts/connect_to_mysql.php";
// Determine which page ID to use in our query below 

if (!$_GET['pid']) {
    $pageid = '1';
} else {
    $pageid = ereg_replace("[^0-9]", "", $_GET['pid']); // filter everything but numbers for security
}

// Query the body section for the proper page
$sqlCommand = "SELECT text1, text2 FROM page_hem WHERE id='$pageid' LIMIT 1"; 
$query = mysqli_query($myConnection, $sqlCommand) or die (mysqli_error()); 
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) { 
    $body1 = $row["text1"];
    $body2 = $row["text2"];
} 
mysqli_free_result($query); 
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

</head>

<body>

<div class="container">

<div class="home-page main">
    <section class="grid-wrap" >
        <header class="grid col-full">
            <hr>

        <form id="form" name="form" method="post" action="page_edit_parse.php">

        <div class="grid col-two-thirds mq2-col-full">
            <label>Titel:</label>
            <textarea name="body1" id="body1" cols="3" rows="2"><?php echo $body1 ?></textarea>
            <label>Meddelande</label>
            <p><textarea name="body2" id="body2" cols="6" rows="10"><?php echo $body2 ?></textarea></p><br>
        </div>


         <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Update!" />
    </form>

    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

**And here is the page_edit_parse.php**

```
<?php
// You may want to obtain refering site name that this post came from for security purposes here
// exit the script if it is not from your site and script
    $body1 = $_POST["text1"];
    $body2 = $_POST["text2"];

include_once "../scripts/connect_to_mysql.php";
// Add the updated info into the database table
$query = mysqli_query($myConnection, "UPDATE page_hem SET text1='$body1', text2='$body2', lastmodified='now()' WHERE id='$pid'") or die (mysqli_error($myConnection));

echo 'Updated, yeah! <br /><br /><a href="kpanel.php">Go back!</a>';
exit();
?>
```

PS: There might be some minor errors on the html due to I edited it so it would be shorter.

Comment: I don't see where you define `$pid`

Comment: also what error do you get and why aren't you escaping your input into the database? this could cause an issue also. i'd recommend PDO with prepared statements instead of mysqli

Comment: 1. `if (!$_GET['pid']) {` use isset. 2. `ereg_replace` is deprecated. i am not sure why you are not getting a notice. turn on error reporting may be? 3. in `page_edit_parse.php`, you haven't define `pid`

Comment: @LiamSorsby `mysqli` has also prepared statement.

Comment: What should I use instead of ereg_replace itachi?

Comment: @itachi my mistake in that case use mysqli prepared statements. thankyou for that

Comment: You may want to look at prepared statements. Your code is severely vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: @itachi depends on his version of php. it's depreciated as of 5.3.0. but still better to change

Comment: @LiamSorsby support to php < 5.3 has been stopped and should not be use in a production.

Comment: Replaced to preg_replace. Still not working...

Comment: __still not working__ is not an error message. tell what is the error.

Comment: @itachi, I wish I had one to give you! Like I mentioned, I am not getting any error message!

Comment: @user2598619 have you got error reporting and logging configured? and is display errors on or off? also is this a live site or a test site?

Comment: The site is running on-line, no simulators. As for the error report the only thing I have on is Firebug and it's not giving me any feedback...

Answer (score 0):

You have error in your select query:

```
SELECT text1, text2, FROM page_hem WHERE id='$pageid' LIMIT 1
                 ^^^ here remove the semicolon
```

Comment: Sorry, that was a mistake, the semicolon is not there

Comment: I did but I erased some stuff so that the code wouldn't be endless. F.I: I have 10 "$body" variables...